# Back to back gigabit network connection

Tags: networking

I have two laptops (both Windows 10) and occasionally need to transfer large amounts of data (15GB - 25GB) between them. Both have gigabit network cards as well as wifi.

I have set the gigabit network cards to both have fixed IP4 addresses on a different subnet to my wifi network and  tried connection them back to back with 2m network cables (both cat 5e & 6). Both are set to "Auto Negotiataion" for Speed & Duplex, however they will only connect at 100Mbit.

Is there anything else that needs to be set to enable 1Gbit data transmission? I would prefer not to have to buy a network switch or other hardware. 
I know I won't get 1GBit in practice as the hard disks will place a limit on the transfer speed.

Comment: In a lot of these cases I find just using a USB harddrive is actually faster.

Comment: I have tried a USB drive you need to copy to the disk and then transfer it to the other computer and then copy from it, twice as many read/write operations and the swap overhead. The each copy operation took as long as the 100Mb network transfer. So for me it took more time.